# Which character names come from Spanish words?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Recently, it's been revealed that the god of destruction from universe 9, the dwarf-like one is named Sidra which comes from the Spanish name for cider. My question is: are there any other characters in the Dragon Ball universe with a Spanish name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fan wiki for Dragon Ball has a page where they've [compiled a list](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Origins_of_character_names) of origins for character names in the Dragon Ball universe.

This page lists three with connections to Spanish.

- Pan

  > Pan means "bread" in both Spanish and Japanese, which may continue the food theme of Gohan's family.
- Chi Chi

  > Japanese for "milk" (which also refers to breasts by extension and are a slang term for breasts in Latino Spanish). Named like this because her father is the Ox-King.
- Salza

  > The English verbal translation is a pun on the Spanish sauce "salsa".

I'm doubtful the first two were intentional, since the Japanese word for bread being the same as the Spanish word is merely a coincidence, and Chi Chi being a slang for breasts also seems very coincidental.